# Validate a date to a specific month

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, validation

I'm using SharePoint Online and in one of the lists I have a date field that need a special validation. The date register by the user must belong to a specified month, and this month most be configurable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following formula in column settings -> column validation:

`=(MONTH(ColName)=MonthNo)` and give a custom validation message.

For eg: for August, this will be `(Month(ColName)=8)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PreSave() function in the newform.aspx.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
 function PreSaveAction() { 
   var dataValue= $j(":input[title='YourDataField']").val(); 
   if(dataValue == yourValue){        
      return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
</script>
```

You can save the configurable value to a list and get it with the Rest API in the PreSave() action.